# Android Studio re-installing every time I open the application on my laptop

Tags: android, android-studio

I am new to android studio and want to start building apps to improve my programming skills.

I have downloaded android studio for the first time and have created a shortcut in my desktop. However every time I run the application (through the shortcut or the main application located in the main file), it re-installs and overrides what I have already installed rather than just opening and running android studio.

Any help on what I can do about this please? Thank you!

Comment: What OS?   Did you shortcut the installer instead?

Comment: Check the shortcut path and compare it with the default Linux or Windows path.

Comment: @tsizzle9, any updates why this happened?

Answer (score 1):

Click on cancel on the setup wizard and it will bring a dialogue box with the option to prevent setup wizard future launches. Look at image attached.[image: ddialog box to prevent setup wizard re-runs]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is not installing properly. Try to look at your installed programs and see if you can find it. If you don't find it, you are having some installation problem. Also, make sure you are not running the instaltor instead of the shortcut.

Comment: Thank you Rafael, it turned out my laptop was messing up

Answer (score 0):

Do not use the file that you downloaded from your browser as a shortcut, it is the installer.

You should search the installation path.
By default in Linux it is:
`/opt/android-studio/bin/studio.sh` or `/usr/bin/android-studio/bin/studio.sh`

Answer (score 0):

Your opening the android studio installer, Follow these easy steps, it works for me.
Go to search bar on windows, type android studio pin it to start or taskbar. Whenever you open an android studio open from the taskbar or which you have pinned to start.

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

May be you are opening the installer that's why it keeps re-installing.

To open the Android studio, go to the bin folder.
In my system path is like that
`C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\bin`. And here open the studio64 Application.